# How to set no cache on only the index.html page in NGINX

Tags: caching, nginx, cache-control

My current project is almost working with the following configuration:

```
root %%COMP_WEB_ROOT;

# COMP Static File serving
location /comp {
    alias %%COMP_WEB_ROOT;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate';
}

# Hide the index file, not exposing that path specifically
location = /index.html {
    internal;
}
```

With this, I am preventing caching for the entire application, which is not desirable, since I only want to prevent the index.html page from storing cache.

So I have tried to put the `add_header` line inside the second block like this:

```
root %%COMP_WEB_ROOT;

# COMP Static File serving
location /comp {
    alias %%COMP_WEB_ROOT;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    error_page 401 = @error401web;
}

# Hide the index file so that we're not exposing that path specifically
location = /index.html {
    internal;
    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate';
}
```

NGINX is able to run, but index.html seems to still storing the cache as if the `add_header` isn't there.

Is there some other command I am missing?

Answer (score 17):

> I only want to prevent the index.html page from storing cache.

- no-cache: prevents from reusing the resource without validating it
- no-store: prevents from storing the cache on client side

In your case I'd try this:

```
location = /index.html {
    internal;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store';
}
```

...and then CTRL+F5 to force refresh all resources in your browser.
From this point your index.html should work in the way you wanted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  One question though, if my user is not expected to force refresh, how can I make sure that cache is not saved?  Currently, cache seems still to be stored for index.html.

Comment: Can you see cache-control header being sent from the server?
User don't need to force refresh. I just wanted to be sure that you are testing changes with the latest files and config.

Comment: I see. In my case, I am not seeing the cache-control header when I use add_header inside the location block for /index.html.  I am seeing cache-control when I use add_header inside the location block for /comp.  Do you think I need to modify my try_files line?

Comment: Is this index.html file inside comp directory?

Comment: Sounds great! What is the internal directive for in this use-case?